Retrieve value from different tables based on column value
I have a challenge where I am combining records where the "result" value can be a different data type depending on the result type. I am trying to simplify this as much as possible so that users do not have to write functions, custom joins or criteria to get what they need.
Consider this example - Results table:



Record ID
Result Type
Result Value ID




1
decimal(10,2)
5


2
int
8



Result values table:



Result ID
Result Value




5
114.25


8
3



Is there a way that when a user queries a specific result value record that it automatically returns the result value in the appropriate format by using result_type's value? I have considered creating result_value_int, result_value_decimal, result_value_float etc. tables and then returning a table of result values in the appropriate format, but I hate to introduce a function into the mix unless I have to.
The following pseudo code will not get what I need:
SELECT CONVERT([Result Type], [Result Value]) AS result
FROM [Result Values Table] rv
INNER JOIN [Results Table] rt ON rv.[Result ID] = rt.[Record ID]

I'm trying to structure the schema and determine if functions or another type of join will be needed to return results in the appropriate format. I can't use a single result value field in the results table as I will have to choose something like float that can accommodate all possible numeric values.

Well, there's sql_variant, but some drivers have shoddy support for it. Otherwise you will find that sql server really likes to keep the same datatype per "column". What's wrong with using a single field to store data and have some presentation type column if you really interested in presenting the value differently

You can return a different resultset from a stored procedure each call, but within a given resultset a given column must have a defined datatype. But yeah why not return a resultset with columns in all the main datatypes and the presentation layer works out which one to use?

@DaleK wasn't that in quarantine

@siggemannen ar good point haha

@DaleK i gotta say, not fully on board with that feature. Specially since half comments are for the question style and half are real comments on solution but it all gets wiped

@siggemannen I like it - cos if OP ignores comments for further information it never gets published - so don't have to go through closing them. But I agree it's hard to avoid giving answers, especially when it's a trivial question.

If indeed your goal is for presentation only, you could create another NVARCHAR() column and upon insert into the table, also include the value, formatted your way, in this column. This assumes it's ONLY for presentation and not calculations.

The universal data type (FLOAT) option is the simplest if you only need to store numeric values, but it may lose type precision. Using separate tables per type ensures data integrity but requires more complex queries. JSON/JSONB offers the most flexibility if you're using a database that supports it (like PostgreSQL). Finally, introducing a SQL function or view may simplify the process for users by hiding the complexity of type casting.

Many thanks for the replies - I had a feeling that the "correct" answer would be to have a single float value and convert as needed. However, this data mart will be accessed directly via SQL queries and there will be a variety of individuals using the mart that are no  sophisticated and I want to reduce potential for error. It breaks my normalized heart, but I'm thinking that for their sake it would be best to include more than one column with the correct type (at the moment only integer and a standard decimal with the same precision across data elements) and train them to use that.
